# Row ommission in R when importing csv files

Tags: r

I do not have idea where exactly in the code you include `quote=""` when trying to read in a basic CSV file that is chopping off some rows. Some have suggested I use `quote=""`

For example in the code below, where can i include `quote=""`?

```
data1 <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
```

Comment: Try looking in help using `?read.csv`.  It can be included anywhere in the parenthesis for `read.csv`, because you are specifying the argument name.

Comment: Named arguments can be included anywhere in a function `read.csv(header= FALSE, file = "file1.csv")` is equivalent to `read.csv(file = "file1.csv", header= FALSE)`. Where order matters is if you're not naming arguments. `read.csv("file1.csv", header = TRUE)` works, but `read.csv(TRUE, "file1.csv") will fail